# Spell checking a multi-language org document, set dictionary according to property value

Tags: org-mode, flyspell

Is it possible to use flyspell on an org document where the dictionary is specified by a property variable? For instance

```
* English
  set property to english dictionary

* Italiano
  set property to italian dictionary
```

Flyspell would then use the English dictionary on the English section, the Italian dictionary on the Italian section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me provide an answer as long as there is no better answer. What you are asking for should not be so difficult to achieve, using the [Mapping API](https://orgmode.org/manual/Using-the-Mapping-API.html) and [Property API](https://orgmode.org/manual/Using-the-Property-API.html), if flyspell could run in synchronous mode (via a synchronous process). Unfortunately, it seems that that synchronous use of flyspell is broken (at least here using GNU/linux with Emacs 29). As the ispell code is quite complicated/long, there is no way of fixing this quickly (for me).

Therefore, this answer uses (the default) asynchronous flyspell 'mode' (see `ispell-async-processp`). It seems to work quite fine for highlighting the misspelled words. However, for getting the correct correction suggestions, you have to select the right dictionary manually (using `M-x ispell-change-dictionary`).

For this solution, you can select the dictionary to use for some section via a `:dictionary:` property in a property drawer as follows:

```
* English
:PROPERTIES:
:dictionary: en
:END:

set property to english dictionary

* Nederlands
:PROPERTIES:
:dictionary: nl
:END:

stel de eigenschap in op Engels woordenboek
```

For the dictionary names you can use the names as listed by `M-x ispell-change-dictionary`.

Then use the following function for flyspelling the org buffer:

```lisp
(defun org-flyspell-buffer ()
  (interactive)
  (let* (start end dict regions)
    (org-map-entries
     (lambda ()
       (when start (push (list dict start (point)) regions))
       (setq start (point)
             dict (org-entry-get nil "dictionary"))))
    (push (list dict start (point-max)) regions)
    (dolist (r (nreverse regions))
      (let ((ispell-local-dictionary (car r)))
        (print r)
        (ispell-internal-change-dictionary)
        (flyspell-region (+ (nth 1 r) 3) (1- (nth 2 r)))))))
```

I did not rigorously test this solution, so success may vary, but it seems to work quite fine here.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do everything you need with the [Mapping API]() and the [Property API]()  but assuming you can, it should be somewhat simpler than using the Org Element API. The main thing that might be missing is the region `beg/end` positions: that might require a parsing call from the Org Element API (probably `org-element-at-point` would be enough). One more point: what happens if there is no `dictionary` property in the headline? I haven't tested it out, but by my reading, the section will be skipped - am I wrong?

Comment: @NickD Indeed, I more or less knew there was an easier method (that's why I mentioned the 'better' answer), but I was not aware of the Mapping and Property API's (I had seen `org-map-entries` before, but could not remember its name). Anyway, I agree that those API's are the more appropriate choice here . About the dictionary, if a headline has no dictionary property, then the local value for `ispell-local-dictionary` will be nil and flyspell will use the default dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for adding the links (that I forgot to add :-) ). The updated code looks better to me: in particular, it addresses my concern about skipping sections, I think.

Comment: The last word in the English section "dictionary" is underlined as misspelled (and so does english, which should be capitalized). When I extend the text, i.e. add "and see what happens", then "dictionary" is not underlined as misspelled, but "happens" is.

Comment: I see. It is because, for some reason, `flyspell-region` acts on a region that is a slightly larger than the region passed to it (this might be a bug in `flyspell-region`). Anyway, just increasing the start position passed to `flyspell-region` to 3 places after the start of the headline, seems to fix this 'faulty' behavior. I have updated the code example with the 'fix/workaround'.